# jsx comments throw warnings in browser console

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why does the browser console window report jsx comments as warnings?  The comments are not even in my Bundle.js file.  The issue only happens when there is at least one space before the comment and the comment has to be at the end of the line as in my example below.  I get the warning:

ValidateDOMNesting: #text cannot appear as a child of tbody

```
<table>
   <tbody>  {/*Comment Here with space before it*/}
      <tr>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you compiling that `jsx`? Browsers currently do not support it so it's reading those curly braces and comment as plain text.

If you are compiling it, can you paste the snippet?

Comment: Here is the compiled snippet.  I don't see my comment in it anywhere. React.createElement("table", { style: { 'width': '600pt', 'tableLayout': 'fixed', 'borderCollapse': 'separate', 'borderSpacing': '0', 'pageBreakInside': 'avoid' } },
               React.createElement("tbody", { id: "Remove118" }, " ",
               React.createElement("tr", null, React.createElement("td", { style: { 'paddingBottom': '9pt' } },

Comment: I think your snippet is incomplete. Does the warning says in which line does this happens? I added some missing parenthesis and it works fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXdmRW

Comment: See my example above.  The issue only happens when the comment is at the end of the line with a space before it.

Comment: So the workaround I used was to remove the space before the jsx comment.

Comment: @martriay - If that's the production version of React you've included in the CodePen, it won't display the error message. React's production version strips all error messages (https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html, under "Development vs Production Builds").